# what is a sphinx thread with net_idle state?

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

I use sphinx search engine and sometimes when I run

```
show threads;
```

I see one thread like picture below with "Net_Idle" state among threads that Its "Time" value goes up to 100 seconds and in some cases up to 500 seconds and then automatically disappears.

[image]

What is this thread and when and why it's running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means there's an open connection via sphinxql protocol. You can easily reproduce it if you just open 2 connections to your searchd at the same time, then in any of them you will see that the other one has a connection and if you don't do anything there the state will be net_idle. E.g.:

```
Tab 1:
[snikolaev@dev01 ~]$ mysql -P9314 -h0
mysql>

Tab 2:
[snikolaev@dev01 ~]$ mysql -P9314 -h0
mysql> show threads;
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+
| Tid   | Proto    | State    | Time     | Info         |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 16626 | sphinxql | query    | 0.000001 | show threads |
| 16598 | sphinxql | net_idle | 3.774544 |              |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you don't know who keeps the connection open you can use lsof, netstat and ps or other tools that do the same to trace that down, e.g.:

```
[snikolaev@dev01 ~]$ lsof -p 14267|grep TCP
searchd_o 14267 snikolaev    6u  IPv4 568694105      0t0       TCP *:9314 (LISTEN)
searchd_o 14267 snikolaev   13u  IPv4 568804452      0t0       TCP localhost:9314->localhost:24228 (ESTABLISHED)

[snikolaev@dev01 ~]$ sudo netstat -apn|grep 24228
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9314              127.0.0.1:24228             ESTABLISHED 14267/./searchd_old
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:24228             127.0.0.1:9314              ESTABLISHED 28949/mysql

[snikolaev@dev01 ~]$ ps aux|grep 28949
518      28949  0.0  0.0 234088 10596 pts/58   S+   23:49   0:00 mysql -P9314 -h0
```

In my case I can see that the connection is from "mysql", in your case it may be different.

Comment: Your answers are always great.